# Subscribe to a group of consumers using RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I'm not entirely certain this is the right place to ask, but I have questions about the functioning of RabbitMQ to implement a publish/subscribe messaging system. I am investigating RabbitMQ to see if it fits the needs of the company I work for, and I can't find any answer to these questions either in the official doc or on the internet :

- Is it possible for a consumer to subscribe to a group of publishers? I guess it could be possible, if all publishers from the group we want to subscribe to send their messages to an exchange that then forwards them to the subscriber(s). What would be the most suitable exhange type to implement this?
- Is it possible to subscribe to a group of topics? For example if we have several topics starting by "data", like data_1, data_2 etc, would it be possible to have consumers subscribe to "data*" ? I didn't find anything on this but from what I gathered on how exchanges work it doesn't seem possible.
- Is it possible to have sub-topics, and even sub-sub-sopics? 
  From what I understand so far, using a topic or header exchange, sub-topics and sub-sub-topics would basically be parts of the routing key, like data.diag.signal for example.

I hope I made myself clear enough and I thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will use Java API examples in my answer.

> Is it possible for a consumer to subscribe to a group of publishers?

RMQ consumers are not aware of publishers. The entities between them are queues (and exchanges, from producer(publisher) side).
The Java API `com.rabbitmq.client.Channel.basicConsume(String, Consumer)` allows for consumption from one queue only. But you could pass the same `Consumer` callback to multiple queues

An alternative would be to create per-consumer queue, and use `channel.queueBind` to bind it to exchanges producing interesting messages. Or even easier, have them publish to some generic exchange and bind to that one.

> Is it possible to subscribe to a group of topics? For example if we have several topics starting by "data", like data_1, data_2 etc, would it be possible to have consumers subscribe to "data*" ? I didn't find anything on this but from what I gathered on how exchanges work it doesn't seem possible.

Not explicitly, as you need to pass in the queue name.
But you can work around with exchange routing:
If your current state is:

```
producer1 -> exchange-data-1 -> queue-data-1
producer2 -> exchange-data-2 -> queue-data-2
producer3 -> exchange-data-3 -> queue-data-3
```

You could also set up a new exchange

```
producer1 -> exchange-data-1 --\ 
producer2 -> exchange-data-2 -> exchange-data-all -> queue-per-consumer -> your-consumer
producer3 -> exchange-data-3 --/
```

> Is it possible to have sub-topics, and even sub-sub-sopics? From what I understand so far, using a topic or header exchange, sub-topics and sub-sub-topics would basically be parts of the routing key, like data.diag.signal for example.

There is no sub-topic concept in RMQ, but, as you had mentioned, you can use `topic` (or even `headers`, for richer designs) exchanges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful! Concerning the wildcards of topic exchanges, I understand it is possible to subscribe to topics such as A.B.* or A.*.*, but is it possible to subscribe to something like A.*.C ?